Location manager error KCLErrorDomain error 1
I created an iOS app compatible watchOS app which was running perfectly fine before I updated my Xcode to use iPhone16.
But after updating, I started to get kclErrorDomain error: 1 and I am not sure why is it happening after update.
I am trying to use coreLocation module as-
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var location: CLLocation?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
                self.location = location
                print("Updated location: \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            } else {
                print("No locations received")
            }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to find user's location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

and I am trying to use it as-
@StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
  guard let currentLocation = locationManager.location else {
            signInError = "Location not available"
            isLoading = false
            return
        }

        let latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude

I tried-

Changing plist file values for the target
Simulating the location from Xcode

but those solutions aren't helpful.
I am assuming it is some error after recent Xcode update, and not from my code since it was working fine before.
Can someone help me?

You should always print(error) rather than error.localizedDescription
